# What does ls -alh mean?

Tags: man, options

I have seen that people use `ls -alh` in the Linux terminal. However, when I see the manual, I don't see `-alh` (i.e. when I type `man ls`).

Why do I not have it in the manual? Can someone explain what it does?

Comment: Personally, I prefer `ls -lhA` which is the same as `-lha` except that it excludes `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ls -alh` is the same as `ls -a -l -h`.

Multiple short options can be combined like this.

Here are the meanings of those options from `man ls`:

```
-a, --all
    do not ignore entries starting with . 

-l
    use a long listing format 

-h, --human-readable
    with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Comment: Why would I need *human readable*? I don't see any differences in the size of the font input...

Comment: @PichiWuana The size of the *files and directories* are printed in a human readable form, and not in bytes (which may be hard to parse if they are big numbers).

Comment: @PichiWuana human readable is not about the font size. It's about printing `1M` instead of `1048576` when listing a file of one megabyte.

Comment: Ohhh.... I understand now.

Comment: In fairness, it's still "human readable" without the `-h` flag, although `-h` does make it easier ;)

Comment: Of course, I prefer to use `ls -hal` for HAL9000-readable.

Answer (score 5):

`-h` stands for *human readable*.

As mentioned in the comment, you can combine arguments simply like:  `-alh`. The order is irrelevant.

From `man ls`:

```
   -h, --human-readable
          with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Comment: Do you mean that `ls -a -l -h` is equal to `ls -alh`?

Comment: @PichiWuana exactly, you can combine arguments like that.