# What's the use of -Nur switch in diff command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, diff

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm learning Gnu/Linux from edX. There's an exercise that has the following command:

```
diff -Nur group GROUP > patchfile
```

And I've no idea what the `-Nur` switch does here.
I checked the man page of `diff`, but it has no mention of `-Nur`. Is it obsolete or is it specific to distribution? If it isn't, what's it's purpose and why it's missing in the man page?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294627/what-does-ls-alh-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Nur` is a shortcut for `-N -u -r`.  From `man diff`:

> ```
>    -N, --new-file
>           treat absent files as empty
>    -u, -U NUM, --unified[=NUM]
>           output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context
>    -r, --recursive
>           recursively compare any subdirectories found
> ```